# What are Nitya karma of a Brahmin?

Tags: rituals, brahmins, life

What are must to do daily ritual for a brahmin.

Comment: Im thinking about drinking water from a copper vessel in morning and night.

Comment: ”What are your daily habits? Any recommendations to a student?" The first sentence could mean you are asking for subjective answers. Asking for what should be daily practices of a Brahmin and asking what Brahmins on this site are different questions. Seems like you are asking for latter?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I will delete this Q.. Can you answer this question >> [Lord_Rama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37502/names-of-mantra-sutra-shloka-and-stotra-from-ramayana)

Comment: This might be Helpful.. [Nitya Kriya](https://www.salagram.net/sstp-NityaKriya.html)    [A Copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20200205130503/https://www.salagram.net/sstp-NityaKriya.html)