# Names of Mantra, Sutra, Shloka and Stotra from Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, gods, mantras, rama

List of Names of Mantra, Sutra, Shloka and Stotra or anything; **Recited_Chanted by Lord_Rama.**

I know about

1. Bala Atibala
2. Aditya Hrudayam

are there any other?

Comment: I know about Bala Atibala and Aditya Hrudayam, are there anything else.

Comment: List like Qs are too broad to answer...

Comment: @Rickross ^^This Q

Answer (score 3):

### A partial answer

Apart from Aditya Hridayam and Bala and Atibala, the following are coming to my mind now.  I will update later with some more, if found.

**Sutra/Sloka stated by Sri Rama**

> सकृद् एव प्रपन्नाय तव अस्मि इति च याचते ||६-१८-३३ अभयम् सर्व भूतेभ्यो
> ददामि एतद् व्रतम् मम |
>
> "He who seeks refuge in me just once, telling me that I am yours', I
> shall give him assurance of safety against all types of beings. This
> is my solemn pledge"

---

**Mantra/stotra**

Sri Rama recited (Gayatri) Supreme Mantra daily, at twilight period.

> तस्यर्षेः परमोदारं वचः श्रुत्वा नरोत्तमौ | स्नात्वा कृतोदकौ वीरौ
> जेपतुः परमं जपम् || १-२३-३
>
> On hearing the benign words of the sage those valorous and best ones
> among men got up, bathed, and on offering water oblation they
> meditated upon the supreme hymn, namely Gayatri.