# Mantra on God of Energy Shakti?

Tags: mantras, shakti

Any powerful Mantras on God of Energy? Or Mantra for energy so that I never get tired? I know about Bala Atibala. I have had Upanayana.

Comment: I know about Bala Atibala.

Comment: Goddess of energy/power is Parvati. But you can't start chanting mantra without Guru diksha. So it would be better to chant name instead of chanting mantra.

Comment: I have had Upanayana.. Is that same as Guru Diksha.. Does every Mantra I want to chant needs to be sung in my ear by the person who did my upanayana?

Comment: You can chant mantra only after getting it from eligible Guru. This link might help you to know more [Is it a sin to chant mantras without initiation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation)

Comment: I thought Upanayana and Guru Diksha are same.. I thought I can chant any mantra since I've had Upanayana...

Comment: Do I have to get Guru Diksha for every mantra I want to say.. like make a list of mantras and ask the person, who did my upanayana; if Im eligible to sing this or not.

Comment: _Do I have to get Guru Diksha for every mantra I want to say_ I am not sure about every mantra. I also wanted to chant Dwadasakshari Mantra of Lord Vishnu but unfortunately couldn't dare to chant after reading here that we won't get any benefit on chanting without getting it from Guru. But instead we will ended up committing sin. That's why naama japa is better if one don't have Guru. Nama japa don't require Guru Diksha.

Comment: OK..Understood. .What is nama japa for God of energy Shakti/Parvati.

Comment: If you want to chant Goddess Parvati name since she is Goddess of power and strength, then Mata Parvati has many names. You can chant any, Naama japa can be done any time i.e. while traveling or while doing any work. OR as a better alternate, you can do dhyana of Parvati, for that close your eyes and try to imagine her image for as long as you can. This is called yoga sadhna without Mantra. You just need to keep her image in mind. If you can, keep imagine her even when your eyes are open. Keeping thoughts of Parvati in mind is enough to get her blessing.

Comment: Thank You So Much. @Vishvam

Comment: Can You Look into this Q >> [Lord_Rama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37502/names-of-mantra-sutra-shloka-and-stotra-from-ramayana?noredirect=1#comment120322_37502)